# How to allocate a derived type-parameterized (Fortran 2003)?

Tags: gfortran, derived-types, fortran2003

Am testing the derived type parameterized. the array  in the derived type contains a scalar expression .
For example :

```
 integer :: a(n+2)
```

I used the intel compiler version 18.0 . It works perfectly . But with gfortran 8.3 am having an internal compiler error

For example:

```
 public 
  type  mytab(n)
    integer, len :: n
    integer :: tab1(n)
    integer :: tab2(n*2)
  end type mytab

contains

  subroutine create(pt1, n)    
    type(mytab(:)),allocatable, intent(out) :: pt1
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    allocate (mytab(n)::pt1)   
  end subroutine
```

The allocation works only for tab1 and not tab2

this is what a get as an error.

```
 allocate (mytab(n)::pt1)


internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_expr_op, at fortran/trans-expr.c:3498
0x5c5fa9 gfc_conv_expr_op
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-expr.c:3498
0x5c5fa9 gfc_conv_expr(gfc_se*, gfc_expr*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-expr.c:7999
0x704b17 gfc_conv_expr_val(gfc_se*, gfc_expr*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-expr.c:8056
0x704c30 gfc_conv_expr_type(gfc_se*, gfc_expr*, tree_node*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-expr.c:8070
0x6e3401 structure_alloc_comps
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-array.c:9129
0x6e6260 gfc_allocate_pdt_comp(gfc_symbol*, tree_node*, int, gfc_actual_arglist*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-array.c:9405
0x73e4cd gfc_trans_allocate(gfc_code*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-stmt.c:6599
0x6cf5e7 trans_code
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans.c:2001
0x6f5dbb gfc_generate_function_code(gfc_namespace*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans-decl.c:6515
0x6d2fe9 gfc_generate_module_code(gfc_namespace*)
    ../../gcc/fortran/trans.c:2227
0x68612b translate_all_program_units
    ../../gcc/fortran/parse.c:6112
0x68612b gfc_parse_file()
    ../../gcc/fortran/parse.c:6328
0x6cca5f gfc_be_parse_file
    ../../gcc/fortran/f95-lang.c:204
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

Comment: This is simply a compiler bug, and the error message tells you how to report it.  You can also check the given site to see whether it has previously been reported.

Comment: i did report it. still no answer. i was wondering if someone had this bug when working with the derived type parameterized. Thanks anyway